# Which micro usb port if preferable to power pi zero?

Tags: pi-zero-w, power-supply, usb-power

Pi zero w has pwr micro usb and normal micro usb. Both of them can be used to power the pi.

What is the safest way to power pi zero w, via pwr micro usb or data micro usb?

Comment: Since they labeled one power and spent money to add it to the board, why would you not use the suggested port?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why a bounty was needed. Isn't the fact that one port is labelled "power" authoritative enough?

Answer (score 4):

The Pi Zero family has minimal (primitive) power circuitry and no protection.

All 5V connections (including USB) are directly connected (which is in violation of USB specs).

The USB port is intended to power peripherals. It CAN be used to power the Pi (because Raspberry Pi Ltd. left off the circuitry which would prevent this); whether this works depends on the external device. A standards compliant device would only supply 150mA to the Pi.

In fact connecting a powered Pi Zero USB to a computer without a hub risks damage to both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, From a safety point of view, does it matter which port to use (pwr or micro usb)?